# Having list of lat/long value from sqlite database, how to show on Google map in Android?

Tags: android, android-maps

I have stored list of Latitude and Longitude value retrieved from sqlite database,How to draw line between these co-ordinates and show it in map view.
Can anyone help me with some good examples.